# Add Legend to CircleMarker Map

Tags: python, geopandas, folium

I used Folium to make a map that visualizes the population distribution of a number of universities but I'm unable to add a legend to my map.

How can I get the legend on the map?

Attached is the code and a link to the map:

```py
    m = folium.Map(Width = "60", Height = "50", location = [54, 15], titles = 'cartodbd', zoom_start = 2, control_scale = True, prefer_canvas = True)
for idx, row in universities.iterrows():

    # Marker([row['Latitude'], row['Longitude']], popup = "<b>{}</b>".format(row['Name']), tooltip = row['Name'], icon = folium.Icon(color = 'blue', prefix = 'fa',             
    #                                                                                              icon = 'graduation-cap')).add_to(m)
    elements = '<b>Name: {}, Country: {}, Population: {}, Rank: {}</b>'.format(row['Name'], 
                                                           row["Country"],
                                                           row['No. of FTE Students'], 
                                                           row['Rank'])
    CircleMarker(
        location = [row['Latitude'], row['Longitude']],
        radius = int((row['No. of FTE Students'])/2000),
        popup = elements,
        fill = True,
        color = 'IndianRed',
        key_on = idx,
        threshold_scale = [0,1,2,3],
        fill_color = '#9F2B68',
        fill_opacity = 0.2
    ).add_to(m)


    folium.raster_layers.TileLayer('Stamen Terrain').add_to(m)
    folium.raster_layers.TileLayer('Stamen Toner').add_to(m)
    folium.raster_layers.TileLayer('Stamen Watercolor').add_to(m)
    folium.raster_layers.TileLayer('CartoDB Positron').add_to(m)
    folium.raster_layers.TileLayer('CartoDB Dark_Matter').add_to(m)
    folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
    fullscreen = Fullscreen(position="top right")
    minimap = MiniMap(toggle_display=True)
    draw = Draw(export=True)
    m.add_child(minimap)
    m.add_child(fullscreen)
    draw.add_to(m)
    
    
    
    display(m)
```

[world_university_rankings_2023](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-2_CDqDwbvljWjg2jfVSU4NP0Lr8dlVx/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: If you are trying to display a legend for the radius of the points, it's probably not possible at the moment. Here is a similar question from 2 years ago that is still unanswered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64370379/how-to-add-circle-size-legend-to-folium-map-in-python-and-how-to-annotate-te